# Objects aren't recognized unless manually created

Tags: r, shiny

My server.R file begins:

```
library(shiny)
source("scripts/0-Prepare-Inputs.R")
source("scripts/1-Analysis-Functions.R")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

If I manually execute the two helper scripts, then `runApp()` works as desired. However, if I start by clearing the environment and then allowing the `source()` commands to run the scripts, then two objects created in `0-Prepare-Inputs.R` aren't found. The error appears as such:

```
> shiny::runApp()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5591
Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : object 'sTableTypes' not found
```

`sTableTypes` is generated in the following manner within `0-Prepare-Inputs.R`:

```
sTableTypes <- list(races = c("All", "White", "Black", "Hispanic", "NHWhite", "NHBlack"),
                genders = c("Total", "Male", "Female"))
```

Running only this line allows `runApp()` to function properly.

I need to solve this problem in order to make use of ShinyApps.io.

Things I've tried which don't work:

- Changing the local parameter in `source()`.
- Replacing the `source()` command with all lines of the source files.
- Wrapping the creation of `sTableTypes` in a function that is called in the script file.
- Wrapping the creation of `sTableTypes` in a function that is called as a reactive object.
- Saving `sTableTypes` as an rObject and loading in the source scripts and at the top of server.R.
- Saving `sTableTypes` using super-assignment.
- Saving `sTableTypes` using `assign()` and specifying `envir = .GlobalEnv`.
- Running the scripts, saving the environment using `save.image()` and loading the environment using `load(..., envir = .GlobalEnv)`

All packages are up to date per `update.packages()`, and I'm currently running R version 3.1.1.

Comment: Where is `sTableTypes` used -in `server.r` or `ui.r` or both?

Comment: Oh!!! It's used in both, so I have to source it in both. Works now. Thanks, John Paul.

Comment: Just posted another suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment my suggestion is to source the file in `global.r`. You can just create this file in the same directory as your `ui.r` and `server.r` files. Anything in this file will be avialable to both the ui and the server.